# Restful routing - two users see different pages that perform the same function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a Reports controller and two types of users: companies and customers. Each sees dramatically different pages when they go to view their main 'Reports' page (i.e. what I would usually call the index).

Because these pages are different but are each respective user's main window on reports, what is the best way to organize these in a RESTful way?

So far I have been doing something like index (for companies) and custindex (for customers). Is there a better way?

Note: these pages have more than a couple of simple differences - otherwise some simple `if` or `case` statements based on user type would have sufficed.

Comment: what you mean with 'couple of simple differences' ?

Comment: @Kleber S. - I meant the pages have significant differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid touching the controller and do it in the view with partials:

```
#in app/views/users/index.html.erb
<common html, if any>
<%= render :partial => @user.kind #or whatever method you use to distinguis between them %>
<more common html, if any>
```

Now you just need a "_customer.html.erb" and a "_company.html.erb" partial in that folder.

Comment: would you still do this if the controller code is a bit different for each user as well? (Given the user's different 'types', the queries required can be different to go along with the different HTML).

Answer (score 0):

you could check user type in your controller:

```
def index
  ...
  template = (@type == 'company') ? 'reports/index.html.erb' : 'reports/custindex.html.erb'
  render :template => template
end
```

meaning you'll have two different html.erb files but still have a single 'index' action and render the template according to user type

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's better or worst but you also could have an method called "reports" on each controller. So it will handler each one separately.

And so, treat that on your routes file in easy way.

Just another idea.

Comment: I don't think you can handle that from the routes file since the logic is based on an attribute of user - both types of users are going to the same URL, so they'd match to the same route.  I'm pretty sure the controller is the right place to put this, and the controller can decide which page to render.  The partials that was suggested above is also ok, though it adds business logic to a view, which smells a bit wrong.

Comment: both type of users can be redirect for unique url, they not must be to the same. could be something like companies/reports and customers/reports. I see no problem with this way.